# ¿Cómo se puede traducir «look up from...»?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Esta frase en inglés es muy común creo con ejemplos así: «She looked up from her book and checked the clock...» «He looked up from his phone and said hello...» etc.

Pero no se me ocurre una frase equivalente en español. He buscado en Linguee pero las traducciones son bastante diversas y también a veces me suenan poco natural.

¿Hay una manera para decir la misma cosa en español?

Comment: Levantó los ojos del libro y comprobó el reloj.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dado que en español no existe una forma habitual de añadir a los verbos una indicación de movimiento en cierta dirección (como es posible en inglés usando *phrasal verbs* del tipo de *look up*, *look down*, etc.), lo expresamos con frases hechas. En este caso son posibles:

- *levantar la vista*
- *alzar los ojos*
- *elevar la mirada*

seguidas por la frase preposicional que corresponda (*de... hacia...*). Se pueden intercambiar el verbo y el sustantivo de las frases (*elevar la vista*, etc.) pero no mucho más que eso.